# Mails not showing images in Outlook when using PHP mail function

Tags: php

When I sent emails using PHP's `mail` function it works for Yahoo and GMail accounts, but in Outlook 2007 the images and background images used in the mail are not shown.

How can I make it work for Outlook, too?

My code:

```
<?php

// multiple recipients (note the commas)
$to = "zohaib@sikone.com, ";

// subject
$subject = "Eid Card";

// compose message
$message = '
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Fillon soutient à fond le retour d\'un Grand Prix de France</title>
</head>
<body>
   <p>Le Premier ministre François Fillon, passionné d\'automobile et pilote à ses heures, a apporté un soutien appuyé au retour d\'un Grand Prix de France au calendrier 2013 de la Formule 1, en faisant un passage-éclair vendredi sur le circuit Paul Ricard dans le Var.</p>
      <img src="http://marvelconcepts.net/email%20of%20eidcard/01.jpg" width="500" height="498">
      <div style=" background-image:url(http://marvelconcepts.net/email%20of%20eidcard/01.jpg); width:100px; height:200px; font-size:16px;">
   <p>Le Premier ministre François Fillon, passionné d\'automobile et pilote à ses heures, a apporté un soutien appuyé au retour d\'un Grand Prix de France au calendrier 2013 de la Formule 1, en faisant un passage-éclair vendredi sur le circuit Paul Ricard dans le Var.</p> </div>
</body>
</html>
';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = "From: Eid Card<info@izhar.com>\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: info@izhar.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: info@eizhar.com\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: Drupal\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; 
// send email
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: You probably need to actually attach the image to the E-Mail; many mail clients do not display external images for security reasons.

Comment: while embedding images will make them always show, outlook simply does not support background images.

Comment: tell me is there any solution to display image without blocking message  with php

Answer (score 1):

the outlook email client does not support background images in html formatted email. there's quite a bit of other html and css it and other email clients don't support as well. The best list of support is this one   [CSS Support The Ultimate Guide](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)

Comment: why img tag do not display image in out look it give a text on img click here to download image

Comment: they are not automatically displayed for "security\privacy" reasons

Comment: tell me is there any solution to display image without blocking message  with php

Comment: embedded images are displayed always. yes, but not background ones

Comment: what do u meant by embbed img

Comment: i use embed image but stillnot showing 
<img alt="Embedded Image" width="500" height="402" 
src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEBLAEsAAD..." />

Answer (score 0):

Always display images in outlook:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27045/beginner-make-outlook-always-display-images-in-email-from-specific-senders/

Comment: i have checked this link there is reason of blocking image tell me is there any solution to display image without blocking message  with php